# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'DataField'

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, mode

i tried running my server then i got this `updated_at=models.DataField(auto_now_add=True) AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'DataField'`

Based on the line of the error, here is the code exactly where the error was detected.

```
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=224)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DataField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manaager()
```

Kindly help me as i am new to python

Comment: DataField does not exist as field in Django probably a typo

Comment: Since you're new to Python, my suggestion would be to pay much closer attention to the errors and stack traces you get when you encounter issues like this. They tend to be very informative, like this one, which tells you exactly what and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `DataField`, instead it should `DateField`.
Also `Manaager` should be `Manager`.
Your code should look like this:

```
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=224)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DataField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manager()
```

Comment: Thank you was probably dizzy